# What is the best method to always get 2 decimal places in Oracle?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, number-formatting

What is the best method to always get 2 decimal places in values returned by Oracle?

At the moment I am wrapping all database related PHP functions in `number_format` etc. but I want to move these to be directly inside the SQL query.

Even better is there an environment variable I can set or similar when I am connecting to Oracle so that I do not have to do this?

```
function OrderNetTotal($id) {
    global $dbh;

    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT net_total FROM order_totals WHERE order_no = $id");

    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();

    return number_format((float)$result[0]['0'], 2, '.', '');
}
```

**Note:** I cannot edit database schema etc.

Answer (score 3):

Well you could just use `ROUND()`

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ROUND(net_total,2) FROM order_totals WHERE order_no = $id");
```

Or even better:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT TO_CHAR(net_total,'99.99') FROM order_totals WHERE order_no = $id");
```

Comment: This adds `.00` even if it isn't returned?

Comment: The second returns `######`?

Comment: Because **TO_CHAR** returns a string, not a number. If you want to retrieve the data type, use ROUND. To handle the zero or null values, use decode and nvl. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Depends whether you just want to display the number in a format or you want to do some arithmetic.

To display, use **TO_CHAR** with **format modifier**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(123456.7890, 'fm9999999.99') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(123
-----------
123456.79
```

The **data type** of the **output** is **string** and not a **number**.

To round off, and let the data type remain as number, use **ROUND**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT ROUND(123456.7890, 2) FROM dual;

ROUND(123456.7890,2)
--------------------
           123456.79
```

You could use **DECODE** to not round off when the number is zero and use **NVL** to handle the null values.

```
SQL> WITH data AS
  2    ( SELECT 123.456 num FROM dual UNION
  3    SELECT NULL FROM dual UNION
  4    SELECT 0 FROM dual
  5    )
  6  SELECT num, NVL(DECODE(num, 0, 0, ROUND(num, 2)), 0) num FROM data;

       NUM        NUM
---------- ----------
         0          0
   123.456     123.46
                    0
```